# Manually changing an employees department in Report only

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to get an employee to show on a ssrs list report that uses a parameter for Department under Human Resources, however, the Employee is not in that department. How can I manually add him to Department in the report without actually changing his department in the database?

Comment: `union all` comes to mind, but your question is too broad without sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you show the query that is being used to generate the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IIF statement in the SSRS report to check for the employee in question and then display HR if it is that employee otherwise use the department field, like:

```
=IIF(Fields!Employee_ID.Value = 1234, "HR", Fields!Employee_Dept.Value)
```

If it was just one place where you need it, then use it in the text box expression.

Since you want to use the department with a filter, add a **Calculated Field** to the dataset with the same expression. You would need to use the dataset filter to use your parameter instead of passing it to the query through the Parameters tab of the dataset.

The other way would be to add a similar CASE statement to your SQL:

```
CASE WHEN Employee_ID = 1234 THEN 'HR' ELSE Employee_Dept END AS DEPT_ADJ
```

Of course, I am just guessing at your field names and **ass**u**me**ing that you have the ID and dept in the data.